# Java - Issue with assigning subclass into superclass two-dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm creating an RPG with a display system which is organized by having each Item in the system be assigned to a spot in a two-dimensional array (locations[][]) based off its x and y values. The classes I use are as such:

- Item -> Entity -> Player
- Item -> Entity -> Enemy
- Item -> Stationary -> Healer

I store the entities in an ArrayList (entities) and the stationaries in an ArrayList as well (stationaries) to have a list of what is in the system. My issue is with setting a value of locations (say, locations[2][2]) to a healer object, while setting that value to a player causes no issue. Setting locations[2][2] to an entity works, but setting it to a stationary throws ArrayStoreException.

Here is the relevant code:

```
  for(int i = 0; i < entities.size(); i++) {
    //System.out.println(i);
     //System.out.println(entities.get(i).getName());
     if (entities.get(i).getX() == 0 || entities.get(i).getY() == 0) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + entities.get(i).getName() + " does not have any coordinates.");
     }
     else {
        locations[entities.get(i).getX()][entities.get(i).getY()] = entities.get(i);  //Works fine
        //System.out.println(entities.get(i).getName() + " " + entities.get(i).getX() + " " + entities.get(i).getY());
     } 
  }
  for(int i = 0; i < stationaries.size(); i++) {
     //System.out.println(i);
     //System.out.println(stationaries.get(i).getName());
     if (stationaries.get(i).getX() == 0 || stationaries.get(i).getY() == 0) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + stationaries.get(i).getName() + " does not have any coordinates.");
     }
     else {
        //System.out.println(stationaries.get(i).getName() + " " + stationaries.get(i).getX() + " " + stationaries.get(i).getY());
        locations[stationaries.get(i).getX()][stationaries.get(i).getY()] = stationaries.get(i);  //Throws exception
     } 
  }
```

If you need anything more to understand the problem, please let me know. Thank you.

Edit:  beginning code:

```
private int height;
   private int width;
   private Item[][] locations;
   private ArrayList<Entity> entities;
   private ArrayList<Stationary> stationaries;
   private Entity placeholder;

   public Map (int h, int w) {
      height = h;
      width = w;
      locations = new Entity[h+1][w+1]; //I just saw this, found it
      entities = new ArrayList<Entity>();
      stationaries = new ArrayList<Stationary>();
      placeholder = new Entity("%$()@&)(*#*@%()$&#()@DFHUVON$r93v80qmwdzl4t3");
      for (int i = 1; i < w + 1; i++) {
         Arrays.fill(locations[i], placeholder);
      }
      locations[0] = null;
   }
```

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Have you declared locations as type Item?? It seems that you have declared it as type Entity, from what i gather.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ArrayStoreException is thrown to indicate that you are trying to store wrong type of object into the array. The type of locations array should be Item.

Please see 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayStoreException.html.

Answer (score 0):

Array by definition is a collection of similar elements. Here stationaries and entities are different elements which you are trying to store in location array which is why its failing

Comment: They are allegedly both items, though. If the location array accepts items, it should accept both.

Comment: i guess he updated the question now. If they are both items it should accept

Comment: The problem here definitely is how the objects are declared. locations array should have a type where it can accept both entity and stationaries

Comment: I'll update with the declarations of the storage systems

Answer (score 0):

After taking a second look at it, it turns out I forgot to change over the locations array from entity to item in the constructor method (the program worked differently before, I changed it up since then).  Thank you everyone for your help.